# Amenability of $S^{\infty}$

Tags: gr.group-theory, topological-groups, amenability

Let $G$  be  the  group of all permutations  of $\mathbb{N}$.  If I am not mistaken, this  group is denoted by $S^{\infty}$.

Is there  a precise locally compact topology on $G$ such that $G$ would  be  an amenable group? Or is  $G$ isomorphic  to a  dense subgroup of  an amenable group?

Comment: I am afraid that the unique locally compact group topology on $S^\infty$ is the discrete topology.

Comment: @TarasBanakh  And the discrete one is not amenable. But is it isomorphic to a dense subgroup of an amenable group?

Comment: I think that your two questions are equivalent: $S_\omega$ admits a non-discrete locally compact topology if and only if $S_\omega$ is isomorphic to a dense subgroup of non-discrete locally compact topological group. This can be shown using the fact that the topology of point-wise convergence is the smallest group topology on $S_\omega$. So, now I am thinking on the existence of a non-discrete locally compact group topology on $S_\omega$ and cannot find a quick answer (neither my collegues - Ravsky, Gutik --  that work in this field). This is an interestng question.

Comment: @AliTaghavi In the second question, you probably mean a subgroup of a _locally _compact amenable group. With its usual Polish topology, $G$ is amenable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293614/is-each-locally-compact-group-topology-on-the-permutation-group-discrete/293619#293619) implies that each locally compact group topology $\tau$ on the permutation group $S^\infty$ is discrete. Since the discrete group $S^\infty$ is known to be non-amenable (it contains a free group with two generators), the locally compact topological group $(S^\infty,\tau)$ is not amenable.

By **Corollary** in the answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293614/is-each-locally-compact-group-topology-on-the-permutation-group-discrete/293619#293619), the permutation group $S^\infty$ is not isomorphic to a dense subgroup of a non-discrete locally compact group. This implies that $S^\infty$ is not isomorphic to a dense subgroup of an amenable locally compact group.

Comment: Thank you very much for  your attention to my question and your great answer.